# Primefaces tab header style

Tags: css, primefaces, tabs, ribbon, tabview

Could someone help me hide tab headers with css?
I'm using primefaces controls and there is one general tabview on page. And there's one tabview(ribbon) on each tab of general tabview.
I need hide all tabs headers of child tabview, but show tabs headers of general tabview.

I've try to make it by using

```
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-top > .ui-tabs-nav {
    display: none!important;
}
```

But this code hides all headers.

My code:

```
<ui:composition template="./../WEB-INF/pagesTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="centralTable">
                <p:tabView id="tabview"
                           value="#{tabView.tabList}"
                           widgetVar="wtabview"
                           style="height: 100%"
                           dynamic="true">
                    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabView.onTabChange}"/>
                    <c:forEach items="#{tabView.tabList}" var="pageUrl">
                        <p:tab title= "#{msg[tabView.getCommonTitleByPage(pageUrl)]}">
                            <ui:include src="#{pageUrl}" />
                        </p:tab>
                    </c:forEach>
                </p:tabView>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Example tab of general tabview:

```
<p:tab title="#{msg['header.Main.Model']}">
        <p:ribbon id="ribbonPannelModel">
            <p:tab title="Model" id="tabModel" >
                <p:ribbonGroup label="#{msg['header.Common.Editing']}" id="rgModelEdit">
                    ...
                </p:ribbonGroup>
            </p:tab>
        </p:ribbon>

        <p:dataTable id="dtModel" widgetVar="wdtModel">
           ...
        </p:dataTable>
</p:tab>
```

And I need to hide  `<p:tab title="Model" id="tabModel" >` - this header

Answer (score 0):

You must use an id for the tabs that you aim and then apply the style to it

`#myTabId .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-top > .ui-tabs-nav {
    display: none!important;
}`

I am not sure about the space between the #myTabId and .ui-tabs try to use and delete it and see the result

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work. I was trying to set as you say style and for child tabviewId and tabId (display: none!important;) but headers still visible. Then I've tried to hide all headers with my css and set style for general tabview (display: block!important;) but with it all headers become invisible

Comment: I've changed my qustion and add my html code to show elements

Comment: In my experience with primefaces, the best way is to try to inspect the elements using your browser (firefox or chrome) and then apply the display property to the inspected  elements then you can see the live result

Answer (score 0):

Just add the styleClass "hideTabHeader" to p:tabView styleClass.

```
<p:tabView id="idXYZTabView" styleClass="hideTabHeader" ..
```

And the following to your CSS file:

```
.hideTabHeader > .ui-tabs-nav
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Easy and reusable for other TabView's.